# Custom ActiveModel Validator Ruby

Tags: ruby, validation, activemodel

I would like to write a custom validator for a given validates call:

```
class Worker
  include ActiveModel::Validations  

  def initialize(graph_object)
    @graph_object = graph_object
  end

  attr_accessor :graph_object

  validates :graph_object, graph_object_type: {inclusion: [:ready, :active]}
end

class GraphObject
  attr_accessor :state     
end
```

I would like to validate `Worker#graph_object` based on a `GraphObject#state`. So the `Worker` is valid when the passed in `GrapObject` is in a **:ready** or **:active** state. I would like to reuse as much of the ActiveModel as possible.

Validations documentation describes the process of setting up the custom validator but I can't figure out how to do it.

I think I have to start with this:

```
class GraphObjectTypeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  end
end
```

- **options[:inclusion]** = [:ready, :active]
- **record** is the instance of the Worker(i think...)
- **value** I have no idea (is `value = record.graph_object` ?)
- **attribute** same as for value - no idea

Maybe `validates :graph_object, graph_object_type: {inclusion: [:ready, :active]}` isn't defined right?

Answer (score 2):

OK I think I figured it out - I love puts debugging! Who needs pry!

One way of doing it would be:

```
class GraphObjectTypeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if options.key?(:inclusion) && not_included?(value.type)
      record.errors.add(attribute, "wrong graph object type")
    end
  end

private

  def not_included?(type)
    !options[:inclusion].include?(type)
  end
end
```

- **options[:inclusion]:** `[:ready, :active]` array
- **record:** instance of the `Worker`
- **value:** instance of the `GraphObject`
- **attribute:** `:graph_object` symbol